# Analysis with data from different sources

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, regression-strategies, research-design

I have data from 3 different sources, measuring different variables for different samples taken from the same population (a country). All of the data is from country-wide studies and should be representative of the country's population. E.g. I have data from source 1 about country-wide demographic variables (census-type), data from source 2 about certain beliefs of the population, and data from source 3 about another set of beliefs. I am comparing two countries and have the same data for each of them. I was wondering if there is any way to analyse the relationship between variables in this situation, even if from different sources, as they are all measures from the same population.

What I am trying to analyse is the relationship between the two sets of beliefs from source 2 and 3. I only need the demographic variables as there is evidence they affect the set of beliefs from source 2, so I guess I could just use the demographic details from source 2 instead off the census, but I still would need to use data from a different source for the other set of beliefs.

If it is possible to use/combine data in this way are there any sources I could read to help me through it?
I am very very new to all this so sorry about the confusion.

EDIT: To be clearer, I have 3 sets of data for two countries:

- Set of beliefs 1, taken from the World Values Survey
- Set of beliefs 2, taken from a separate survey (but corroborated by findings from other surveys as well)
- Demographic data for both countries at an aggregate level, taken from each country's National databanks/censuses

My hypothesis is that Beliefs 1 have a relationship to Beliefs 2. As Beliefs 2 are described in the literature as being influenced by certain demographic variables, I also need to consider demographic data to account for that.

I am performing the analysis on each country separately and then comparing the results to see if they are similar (the hypothesis holds up in different contexts) or not (something else is at play).

Comment: How fine-grained is your data? For example, is your data only at the level of the whole country, or do you have data from different sub-regions?

Comment: @Confused If you're looking to say something about individuals (statements like "people from country F who believe A have a 10% higher probability to believe X than people from country G"), you would need individual-level (paired) data, beware the ecological fallacy.)

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated.  Despite the tags you chose, I find this a research-strategy question more than a statistics question. Beyond that, I am unclear on paragraph 1, last sentence:  "same population" even though there are two countries?  Also I am unclear on the choices you are considering in paragraph 2:  there are alternate sources of demographic data besides source 1?  Generally, I doubt there is an easily locatable reference that will squarely address this idiosyncratic situation.  I think it requires having multiple colleagues, or perhaps a coach or mentor, think it through.

Comment: @DavidB I mostly have country-level data.

Comment: @Glen_b my hypothesis is that set of beliefs A has some sort of relation to set of beliefs B. I am trying to verify this in both countries separately, and then discuss the results together to see if there are any differences/similarity and to give possible policy prescriptions. So it is mostly to analyse the relationship in multiple populations rather than just one

Comment: @rolando2 I mean same population because I am doing the analysis separately for the two countries and then comparing the results. The variables that i need to fit into each model are taken from one population each, if that makes sense? (Sorry, english is not my first language) And what I mean in paragraph two is whether I should use a separate source for the demographic data or refer to the demographic info about the participants of the study measuring what would be my dependent variable.

Comment: @ouroboro you need to be able to align the responses across surveys. It sounds like the respondents were not the same in all the surveys, so you cannot simply merge the survey responses. If you had information about where people lived, you could create summary measures for each unit (e.g., county, state, or census tract, etc.) and then merge the different surveys that way. The way you describe it, it sounds like you only have data at the country-level, for two countries. That isn't enough data to conduct the analysis you've described.

Comment: @DavidB thank you very much for your response. I have actually realised I do have regional level data available if I just use a different data source for one of the sets of beliefs. I'll have to re-clean all the data and stuff but that should be ok. What could I do to align the responses? Would you be able to direct me to any resources on how to proceed with the analysis? Thank you again for taking the time to help

Comment: Great, then you'll need to compute a reasonable summary measure for each region (probably the median) and then account for the number of measurements from each region as covariates. For the regression you'll also want to adjust for the spatial proximity between regions. This is a decent primer: https://walker-data.com/census-r/modeling-us-census-data.html

Comment: @DavidB thanks for your help! you're a life saver